# mod_wsgi + python 2.7.5 import error

Tags: python-2.7, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have installed and probably right configurated apache2, mod_wsgi and python 2.7.5. The problem is that 127.0.0.1 is not opening (loading is just freezed) and I see following log in error.log:

```
    [Wed Jun 19 14:49:11 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Tried to restart apache, but it's not working. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer.

Comment: There is still possibly something wrong with your setup. You should go through the checks in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation to verify which Python library mod_wsgi.so is linked against. Looks like you are mixing Python installations, which is bad.

Comment: I think it's not okay, but I have following python dirs: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/ and /usr/lib/python2.7/.'ldd mod_wsgi.so'

Comment: Damned enter :). Command 'ldd mod_wsgi.so' prints that python lib is /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0. Besides there is no similar python lib in /usr/local/lib/. I think that's why I had troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found solution. I checked 'sys.prefix' in my python's interpretator and it printed '/usr/local', but I had not set WSGIPythonHome in apache config (as written in mod_wsgi docs for this case). And just for experiment I set 'WSGIPythonHome /usr'. It's strange, but it resolves my problem, everything is fine now!